# Importing view controllers for delegation not working

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a view controller, FirstViewController, with a subclass, FourthViewController. FirstViewController's interface is:

```
#import "FourthViewController.h"
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <FourthViewControllerDelegate>
```

In FourthViewController's .h, I have:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@protocol FourthViewControllerDelegate
-(void) updateLabel;
@end

@interface FourthViewController : FirstViewController 

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<FourthViewControllerDelegate>delegate;
```

This is giving me the error message: Cannot find interface declaration of 'FirstViewController', superclass of 'FourthViewController'
I'm not sure why this error is occuring. Any advice would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is keeping the delegate in the same `.h` file with the controller really critical to you? I pulled it into a separate `.h` file and the whole thing worked for me. Like this:

```
//FirstViewController.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "FourthViewControllerDelegate.h"
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <FourthViewControllerDelegate>
@end

//FourthViewControllerDelegate.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol FourthViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) updateLabel;
@end

//FourthViewController.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "FourthViewControllerDelegate.h"

@interface FourthViewController : FirstViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<FourthViewControllerDelegate>delegate;
@end
```

Comment: I think it is necessary because I need the updateLabel method to be called when a UIButton is pressed in FourthViewController

Comment: you should be all right as long as you are importing `FourthViewControllerDelegate.h`